# How does Zemo know something happened in 1991?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

Col Zemo is after Bucky's mission report from 1991, but how does he even know it exists?

After all,  it's Captain America he's been studying.